# Is there a way to pass the Jenkins build status into another parametrized job?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which triggers a parametrized build of another job on completion.  This is setup using the Parameterized Trigger Plugin. It is working, and triggering the job correctly.
 https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

I would like to be able to pass in the build status of the first Jenkins job to the second job.  (It is literally just a string that is used, so there is no value in creating a second downstream job and triggering the other one if the job Failed.)

How do I pass the build status to the downstream job?

I've tried using `BUILD_STATUS=${BUILD_STATUS}` in the predefined parameter to pass into the next job.  But this passed in an empty string.

Comment: Almost certainly that is a not implemented functionality in Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin or you are using incorrect variables names. Could you pass other environment vars to the second job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a workaround, I have triggered two Parameterized builds, both triggering the same job.  The first one is on Success, the second on Failure, and these pass in a parameter (success/failure) to the job based on that trigger.